# How can I sort Items in `CListCtrl` when the button is clicked?

Tags: mfc

How can I sort Items in `CListCtrl` when the button is clicked?

I made a Dialog based application in `MFC`.

I put `CListCtrl` control on my Dialog and set its view style to report type.
I have two columns in this list view.

In here when I clicked the `"Sorting"` button, it should sort item in the list.
I saw many examples related to this, but none is working for me.

Can some one guide me how to do that?

Comment: Which code have you tried? What didn't work with that implementation? How are we supposed to give you suggestions with the information you have provided??

Comment: http://blog.naver.com/ddaidock/40072648779

Comment: In this code I must click the column. But that's not what I want.
How can I run the OnColumnclickList1() function when I click the "Sorting" button.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean the column header when you write "sorting button".

You probably forgot to put this into the message map of your dialog:

```
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_COLUMNCLICK, IDC_LIST1, OnColumnclickList1)
```

`IDC_LIST1` is the id of the list control which may be different in your code.

Are you somewhat familiar with MFC ? If not, you should follow one of the numerous tutorials available on the net.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I learned something new from you.
But I mean I want to auto sort Items in CListCtrl with no any operations such as OnLvnColumnclickList().

Comment: @hitman.star you can't. It's up to _you_ to write the code, but in the link you provided in one of your comments, the `OnColumnclickList1` method is more or less what you need.

Comment: Sorry, I am beginner of mfc programming. So, I hope your more detailed explanation.

Comment: @hitman.star on this site we can't give you a detailed MFC tutorial. We only can answer _specific_ questions and this has been done so far.

Comment: Ok, I learned something new from you. Thanks for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `CMFCListCtrl`. It is easier, as it as built in sorting functionality and you only have to provide a function with the comparing items algorithm for sorting. I have succeeded using it. You have to override the `OnCompareItems` on your class derived from `CMFCListCtrl`. I also recommend you to do a call to `EnableMarkSortedColumn();` after your list is created.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain how to you have succeeded it?

Comment: I don't know if you are using a custom class from yourself, or a `CListCtrl` directly. For the first case, changing your class to be derived from `CFMCListCtrl` should not be difficult, as `CMFCListCtrl` is direct child of `CListCtrl`.

Answer (score 0):

The **CListCtrl** has a [SortItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4ceh1za.aspx) method.

All you need to do is provide your **Compare** function to it as the parameter.

I don't know much about the contents of your list control so I  can't really give you more information.

Please read up on it and extend your question with example code and details of which column needs to be sorted and I  can help more.

If the contents of your cells are just text then I usually just return the value of:

```
return Value1.CollateNoCase(Value2);
```

There are also lots of tutorials on the Internet. For example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27774/CListCtrl-and-sorting-rows

In fact, that tutorial suggests us in [SortItemsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387110.aspx). That is what I would use.